# Hows to get rid of this message on iOS devices when using Azure AD B2C

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have finally managed to get **Azure AD B2C** working on our iOS mobile app which we have developed using **Xamarin.Forms** and VS 2017 v15.9.4. We are using the latest version of **MSAL** v2.6.2.

However, we are getting this message come up when they go to the login screen of our mobiloe app on iOS.

[image]

If they click continue they can login using their credentials, but we'd prefer if this dialogue didn't come up as it's bound to cause confusion with our customers. No such dialogue comes up when using Android.

I have tested this on devices using iOS v11.1.2 and 12.1.2 and we see this on both. Is this a permission or something?

Comment: Here's an explanation why it is happening: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/177#issuecomment-345875180

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's an iOS permission which we have no control over.

Comment: That dialog is coming from iOS itself and is associated with this type of authentication flow.It is currently not possible to bypass that screen when using SFAuthenticationSession.